# fetching data from ldap server using java

Tags: java, ldap

Please find my code snippet below:

```
String[] attrIDs = {"title", "Depatrment", "DivisionDescription" };

SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
ctls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs); 
ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(ldapServerSearchBase, FILTER, ctls);
SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) answer.next(); 
Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();

String str_title = attrs.get("title").toString();

String str_dept = null;
String str_desc = null;
if(str_title.equals("Professor"))
{
    str_dept = attrs.get("Depatrment").toString();
    str_desc = attrs.get("DivisionDescription").toString();
}
System.out.println(str_title);
System.out.println(str_dept);
System.out.println(str_desc);
```

When I run this code, it always displays null when i output str_dept and str_desc. But it does display str_title correctly as "Professor".
Please help me understand what could be going wrong here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the attributes you're fetching even exists?

```
str_dept = attrs.get("Depatrment").toString();
str_desc = attrs.get("DivisionDescription").toString();
```

Firstly, the `Depatrment` is spelled wrong, and the `DivisionDescription` most likely does not exists (at least not in the default schematics for most directory services). Might be you need the following attributes?:

- `DivisionDescription` => `division`
- `Depatrment` => `department`

However, check that your directory service actually even posess the requested attributes (and that users actually have some values within these attributes).

Comment: yes the spelling is correct. Thats not the issue. Also only "Professor" category has values for Depatrment  and DivisionDescription and not the "Student", hence the if condition

Comment: I am unable to believe that the spelling is correct. Was your LDAP sysadmin illiterate?

Comment: I have just joined the team.. n this system has been in place for some 3+ years! it has always been this way :P

Answer (score -1):

Although I am sure, if more information were provided, there is a better method to do this, the example below should get you on your way:

```
String[] attrIDs = {"title", "Depatrment", "DivisionDescription" };

SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
ctls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs); 
ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);


NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(ldapServerSearchBase, filter, ctls);
SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) answer.next(); 
Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
String str_title=null;
String str_dept = null;
String str_desc = null;
if( attrs.get("title")!=null)
{
    str_title = attrs.get("title").toString();
    System.out.println(str_title);
    if(str_title.equals("Professor"))
    {
        str_dept = attrs.get("Depatrment").toString();
        str_desc = attrs.get("DivisionDescription").toString();
        System.out.println(str_dept);
        System.out.println(str_desc);
    }
}
```

-jim

Comment: What's better about It?